# eager fetch performs left join in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am defining an entity, myParent, it works fine except for one thing. It has the following defined :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myParent", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Child> children;
```

This causes a left or right join to be performed so I get two parents if there are two children. I don't want that I just want one parent, and two children.

I could change fetchtype to lazy but I didn't really want that ... ?

when I select all parents the list contains duplicate parents, I do not want the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html).

This means that each row of results is a distinct instance of the root entity.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is that the only way ? Or is an annoation and/or paramter availabel to define the the default ?

Comment: You could also use the `SELECT` [FetchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html). This would probably result in additional queries being executed on your DB though so might not be ideal.